# PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, web-development, javascript

I am a good C programmer. I have recently studied a bit of JavaScript and I plan on developing my skills by also learning PHP.

Can I learn both these language in 3 months and after that build a site of mine like a small social network or something in a month.

Comment: Your right it is very objective but as you said people may reply even when its closed. Personally I don't think its doable since C skills are good but mostly if your going to use PHP then its a big difference - It depends on how complex you want your social networking site.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try to be a little polite as well (since generally people ARE trying to help!)

Learning PHP in 3 months is fairly doable. In fact, if you work at it you can do this faster as well!!

Building a social network in a month's time is debatable! It's been more than a decade since I have been programming in PHP, and I will not agree to take this deadline.

Btw, this is a generic answer, however in my defense so is the question! If you want more specifics on how you can get there, try asking more pointed and specific questions.

Comment: Making a well coded, tested and designed social network is impossible in a month, but making a semi-broken and simple one would be doable I guess. The language choice shouldn't have a big impact here.

Comment: Agreed, upvoted for language choice.